# A question on affine cones

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $C=\mathrm{Spec}_S(\oplus_{i\geq 0} A^i)$ and $D=\mathrm{Spec}_S(\oplus_{i\geq 0} B^i)$ be two affine cones over an algebraic scheme $S$. Assume that $A^0=B^0=\mathcal{O}_X$ with $A^1$ and $B^1$ coherent. Moverover, assume that $\oplus_{i\geq 0} A^i$ and $\oplus_{i\geq 0} B^i$ are both locally generated in degree one.

Now given a smooth surjective morphism $p: C \to D$ induced by a degree one graded homomorphism between graded algebras. Let $C':=\mathrm{Spec}_X(\mathrm{Sym}(A^1))$ and $D':=\mathrm{Spec}_X(\mathrm{Sym}(B^1))$. Then we have a induced morphism $p': C'\to D'$ and closed immersions $C\to C'$, $D\to D'$.

My question is: Do we have $C\cong C'\times_{D'} D$?

Comment: Just a quick comment (maybe obvious to you) that it's easy to construct examples without the smoothness condition, for example when $A^i$ vanishes for all $i\geq 2$ but this doesn't hold for $B^i$, so the smoothness is crucial.

Comment: @WillSawin Yes, I agree. Actually, I think it is enough to assume that $p$ is faithfully flat, but I'm not able to prove this yet... Have you seen any similar result?